# Square dot puzzle

Tags: pattern

I have the following sequence of square:

1)

```
xxx
oox
oox
```

2)

```
xxx
xoo
xoo
```

3)

```
oxx
xxo
oxo
```

What should the next shape be and why?

The choices are:

a)

```
xoo
xoo
xxx
```

b)

```
oox
xxx
oox
```

c)

```
oxo
oxo
xxx
```

d)

```
oxo
xox
xoo
```

EDIT:

My guess is b) because you are shifting the

```
x
x
x
```

column (3 to 1 to 2 and back to 3) and repeat. Can someone confirm?

Comment: This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, proper attribution is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at minimum) where it came from. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally deleted.

Comment: Try attributing the source of the puzzle because this doesn't seem to be a puzzle you created yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's:

> B. Because each row is shifted to the right, with overflow appearing on the next row. The last row overflows to the first row.